# Injection function proof

Tags: functions

> Suppose $f$ is an injection. Show that $f^{-1}\circ f(x)=x$ for all
>   $x\in D(f)$ and $f\circ f^{-1}(y)=y$ for all $y$ in $R(f)$.

In $f^{-1}$ it is defined as "Let $f$ be a one-one function with domain $D(f)$  in $A$  and range $R(f)$  in $B$. If $g=\{(b,a)\in B×A:(a,b)\in f\}$  then $g$  is a one-one function with domain $D(g)=R(f)$  in $B$ and with range $R(g)=D(f)$  in $A$. The function $g$  is called the function inverse to $f$."

I know that for it to be an injection the domain of $f$  maps into distinct elements of $y$, but where I am having trouble understanding and proving this is that, what does this $f^{-1}\circ f(x)=x$ mean? the $=x$ threw me off because what is $x$ in this case, could it have been an $x+3$ or $x^2$ instead of $x$?

Is proving this as easy as just showing that since it is injective then if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ $\implies$ $f^{-1}\circ f(x_1)=x_1=f^{-1}\circ f(x_2)=x_2$

Comment: Are we assuming that $ \text{Dom}(f) \subseteq \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: @HaskellCurry Yes we are

Comment: If that is so, then $ (f^{-1} \circ f)(x + 3) = x + 3 $ is valid, as long as $ x + 3 \in \text{Dom}(f) $, or equivalently, $ x \in \text{Dom}(f) - 3 $. Also, $ (f^{-1} \circ f)(x^{2}) = x^{2} $ is valid as long as $ x^{2} \in \text{Dom}(f) $.

Comment: @HaskellCurry Agh, got it. I have edited it you think you can go over it and tell me if I am correct?

Comment: By definition, a function $ f: X \to Y $ is said to be **injective** if and only if $ f(x_{1}) = f(x_{2}) $ implies $ x_{1} = x_{2} $ for all $ x_{1},x_{2} \in X $. You can’t show that $ f $ is injective just by applying some $ f^{-1} $, because if you haven’t proven that $ f $ is injective in the first place, then how can you say that $ f^{-1}: \text{Range}(f) \to X $ exists? :)

Comment: @HaskellCurry But it says in the question it is injective so doesnt that mean i dont have to show it is injective?

Comment: Hmm... Well, I don’t understand why you need to introduce the two variables $ x_{1} $ and $ x_{2} $. To prove the first identity, note that if $ f(a) = b $, then $ {f^{-1}}(b) = a $. Let $ a = x $ and $ b = f(x) $, where $ x \in \text{Dom}(f) $. Clearly, $ f(a) = b $. Then $ {f^{-1}}(b) = a $ is just $ {f^{-1}}(f(x)) = x $, or equivalently, $ {f^{-1} \circ f}(x) = x $. The proof of the second identity is similar.

Comment: @Q.matin Are you sure you copied the question right?

Comment: @HaskellCurry thanks that makes it more clear!

Comment: @GitGud Yup, I just doubled check .

Comment: @Q.matin What's your definition of $f^{-1}$, given a function $f$?

Comment: @GitGud The def given in the book is "Let f  be a one-one function with domain $D(f)$ in $A$  and range $R(f)$ in $B$. If $g=\{(b,a)\in B×A:(a,b)\in f\}$  then $g$  is a one-one function with domain $D(g)=R(f)$  in $B$  and with range $R(g)=D(f)$  in A . The function $g$  is called the function inverse to $f$."

Comment: @Q.matin I suggest you add that information to the question. I gotta go now. When I get back in about 12 hours I'll help you out if  no one else does in the meantime.

Comment: @GitGud That is fine, thanks a lot. Enjoy your 12 hour break .

Comment: @Q.matin You forgot to type \{ when you defined $g$ in the question.You just typed {.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $f^{-1}=\{(b,a)\in R(f)\times D(f) : (a,b)\in f\}$.

Now think of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ as binary relations and compute the composition of the relation $f^{-1}$ with the relation $f$. It comes $f^{-1}\circ f=\{(a,a')\in D(f)\times D(f):(\exists b\in R(f))\bigl( (a,b)\in f\wedge (b,a)\in f^{-1}\bigr)\}$.

(Recall that if $g$ is a function, then saying $g(z)=w$ is just shorthand notation for $(z,w)\in g$).

You want to prove that $(\forall x\in D(f))\bigl((f^{-1}\circ f)(x)=x\bigr)$, i.e., $(\forall x\in D(f))\bigl((x,x)\in f^{-1}\circ f\bigr)$.

Let $x\in D(f)$ be taken arbitrarily... (solution below).

> Define $y=f(x)$. It follows that $(x,y)\in f$. Furthermore $(y,x)\in f^{-1}$. Since $y\in R(f)$ (by definition of $y$), it comes $(x,x)\in f^{-1}\circ f$, which means $(f^{-1}\circ f)(x)=x$.

The other one is similar.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Git. This is very helpful!

Comment: Sir you used? $f$ is injective?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Yes.